# Line chart display in power bi desktop

Tags: date, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, linechart

I have a line chart in my power bi desktop report that summarize the quantity of product sold daily, but I want it to be monthly how do I do that?

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Shj.png)

I tried to create a new column that formats the date field to display the month but it doesn't seem to work